# How to filter array and show string into single place using angular pipe?

Tags: angular, string, pipe, array-filter

I have one array in angular and one form in which I want to replace placeholder's value from that array.

check below code :

```
fieldType = [{
   id: 1, 
   defaultData: {
      inputPlacehoolder: 'enter Text'
   }
 },{
   id: 2, 
   defaultData: {
      inputPlacehoolder: 'enter Email'
   }
 },{
   id: 3, 
   defaultData: {
      inputPlacehoolder: 'enter Value'
   }
}]

fieldArray = [
   {
      type: 1,
      value: "demo"
   },
   {
      type: 2,
      value: "demo@gmail.com"
   }
]
```

### and Here is html code  :

```
<form *ngFor="let field of fieldArray">
    <input type="text" placeholder="{{ fieldType | filterPipe: field.type : 'inputPlacehoolder' }}" />
</form>
```

### and here is my pipe like this :

```
transformPipe(fieldType, id, key) {
    return fieldType.find(item => item.id == id).defaultData[key]
}
```

### expected output should like this :

```
<input type="text" placeholder="enter Text" />
<input type="text" placeholder="enter Email" />
```

I want to filter array and show only one string in html using angular pipe. but this pipe return me error like : **Multiple components match node with tagname**

can anyone please suggest me how to filter array and show only single string in angular ?

I can't call function in that `placeholder` binding because it causes performance issues not even merge that two array for show direct value using loop.

Pipe is the only way. please help me to figure it out...

Comment: do you really have **let** before **fieldArray** in your component?

Comment: Nope, There is a some typing mistake. uff.... Coder's default habit....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try this code:

```
export class FilterPipe implements PipeTransform {
  transform(fieldType: any[], id: any, key: any): any {
    let placeholder =   fieldType.filter(r => r.id == id).length>0? fieldType.filter(r => r.id == id)[0].defaultData
      .inputPlacehoolder:"";

    return placeholder;
  }
}
```

for more view this code:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-mis3fx?file=src%2Fapp%2FfilterPipe.ts

Comment: Thanks for reply. It's working for me. I found one more solution : that I switch my passed argument in pipe and it's getting worked